# Cannot link _wcsicmp on Windows

Tags: windows, linker

I'm compiling de Win32 program that links a lib which calls the Windows function `_wcsicmp`. However I get the link error symbol. I cannot solve it, which system `.lib` contains this method ? It's not explained in the MSDN.
I thought it was `MSVCRT.lib` but it seems not.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: It is not a Windows function, it is a C runtime function.  Yes, defined in msvcrt.lib.  Hard to guess what you are linking, you'll have to post more details.  At least the VS version you are using.

Comment: I'm linking with VS2013